# Splitting a list in python

Tags: python

Hey im new to python. How do you get a portion of a list by the relative value of its sorting key.

example...

```
list = [11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list.sort()
newList = list.split("all numbers that are over 13")
assert newList == [14,15,16]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l = [11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> sorted(x for x in l if x > 13)
[14, 15, 16]
```

or with filter (would be a little bit slower if you have big list, because of lambda)

```
>>> sorted(filter(lambda x: x > 13, l))
[14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Using `lambda` with `filter` and `map` is silly. The list comprehension form satisfies that so much better.

Comment: Note that the result has the numbers in the same order as the original list. If you need them to be sorted you should use `sorted(x for x in l if x>13)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `[item for item in newList if item > 13]`.

There is a decent chance this could be replaced with the generator expression `(item for item in newList if item > 13)`, which filters lazily rather than storing the whole list in memory.

---

You might also be interested in changing the code just a bit to something like

```
all_numbers = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
filtered_sorted_numbers = sorted(number for number in all_numbers if number > 13)
```

which performs the sorting—a worst case O(n log n) operation—on only the filtered values.